# I get error by making snipe command that shows the latest deleted message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command where when you type for example `z!snipe`
it shows you the last deleted message with the author on top, the message in the middle.
but it doesn't work. there aren't many tutorials on youtube on how to do this.

I managed to find one but it doesn't work. the problem is:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

My code is:

```js
const { Discord, RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports ={
    name: "snipe",
    category: "info",
    description: "Shows the most recent deleted message.",
    usage: "z!snipe",
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        const msg = client.snipes.get(message.channel.id);
        if(!msg) return message.reply("There are no recently deleted messages!");

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Deleted by ${msg.author.tag}`, msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(msg.content);
    }
}
```

the guy in the tutorial doesnt show how he gets that snipe thing.. so it doesn't work for me.
I don't know what else to add there, so basically I'm at a dead-end.

Comment: It's telling you ``client.snipes`` is undefined.    It's not a standard part of the client object. Did you create this?   If so, are you sure that part of the code is executed?

Comment: I did not created this.. Yes As i Said there is no such thing as client.snipes.. The guy didnt shows how he made it.. so he actually showed a command that ends up in a dead end.. I don't know what to add in this client.snipes.. I don't know what to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined the `Map()` *or* [`Discord#Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) (a class that extends Map()) for the snipes? The channel id you are trying to get should be a key of said `Map`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of making the `.snipes` for your client. It literally just stores each deleted msg to it's channel ID. You could add more features but this should be enough to answer your question :D

```js
client.snipes = function(){
   get(ChannelId){
       return this[ChannelId];
   }
   set(msg){
      this[msg.channel.id] = msg;
   }
}
client.on('messageDelete',function(msg){
   client.snipes.set(msg); 
}
```